# WIQL: Get only top level items in Iteration asOf specific date

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, wiql

#### What & Why

My goal is to find out, which items where originally planned for a sprint, which items have been added late and which items where moved out of the sprint late

I'm trying to use the Azure Devops Rest API to query all **top level items** of an **iteration** at a specific **point in time** using the following endpoint:

[Azure DevOps Rest API Documentation - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

---

#### How

My first query returns the top level items but sadly only *if there are any children*. At least I can use `asOf` since the `mode(MustContain)` allows it:

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] 
FROM WorkItemLinks

WHERE (Source.[System.IterationPath] = 'Name of the iteration') 
  AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') 
ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc

mode(MustContain)
asof '05/05/2021'
```

The second query I tried returns all top level iteration items, but I cannot specify `asOf`, since the `mode(Recursive)` forbids it:

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]
FROM WorkItemLinks

WHERE [Source].[System.IterationPath] = 'Name of the iteration'
AND [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'
ORDER BY [System.Id]

mode(Recursive)
```

---

### Question

How can I query **all** top level iteration items as they are seen in the `Sprint Backlog`, at a **specific point in time**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `IN GROUP` when filtering for `[System.WorkItemType]` it is no longer necessary to query for `WorkItemLinks` which resolves both issues as we are then able to use `asOf`:

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] 
FROM WorkItems 

WHERE [System.IterationPath] = 'Name of the iteration'
AND 
(
    [System.WorkItemType] IN GROUP 'Microsoft.RequirementCategory' OR 
    [System.WorkItemType] IN GROUP 'Microsoft.BugCategory' 
)

ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc
ASOF '05/05/2021'
```

Comment: Hi @SebastianKrogull, Thanks a lot for sharing your experience. I recommend that you can mark your answer as the solution of this topic. This may be very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BrightRan-MSFT, I can just mark it as an answer 48 hours after posting it. Will do when that happens, thanks.